# Puppet 2D Iteration

Tags: multidimensional-array, puppet

I've got a two dimensional set of configuration variables:

```
$environments = [
  {
    'name' => 'foo',
    'port' => '1234',
  },
  {
    'name' => 'bar',
    'port' => '4321',
  },
]
```

Is it possible to iterate over the arrays and use the variables from the inner arrays. E.g. I want to create an user account for every name.

```
# How to get each name?
user { $environment:
  ensure => 'present'
}
```

Comment: You present an array of hashes that seem (by use of the key `'port'`) to be related to networking, and then ask about creating users.  I don't see the connection.

Comment: In any case, which version of Puppet are you using?  It makes rather a large difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puppet 4 provides [built-in functions](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.2.latest/function.html) for iterating over aggregate values, and new, Ruby-like syntax to go with them.  These are also available in recent enough versions of Puppet 3 when the future parser is enabled.  If you are using such a Puppet, you could approach the problem like this:

```
each($environments) |$e| {
  foo { $e['name']: port => $e['port'] }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem for newer puppet versions. For older versions I had to create a "define" function. This function would only do one task and iterate over the array.

Answer (score 0):

I never really worked with iterations in puppet.

But to create multiple resources from a `hash` (note **hash** not **array**) you can use the `create_resources()` function.

The [documentation](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#createresources) has a good example.

Your `hash` can not contain `parameters` that the `resource` dose not understand tho. In your example `port` would not work with the `user` resource as it dose not understand that parameter.

Hope this helps a bit anyway.

Comment: I might not help for everything I need to do, but it seems like a solid solution for some things. I will look into it, thx.